# Finding $b_n$ for Fourier Series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, integration-by-parts

**Question:**

Why am I not getting the correct $b_n$ for the Fourier series for the given function below? Why does my answer have an $x$ in it?
[image]

**Textbook Answer**

[image]
As shown above $b_n = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$

**My Work (via integration of parts)**
$$
b_n = \frac{1}{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x)sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) dx
$$
$$
b_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{0} xsin(nx) dx
= \frac{-x}{n}cos(nx) + \int_{-\pi}^{0} \frac{cos(nx)}{n} dx
= \frac{-x}{n}cos(nx) + 0
$$
This means that 
$$
    \frac{-x}{n}cos(nx)= 
\begin{cases}
    \frac{-x}{n},& \text{if n is even }\\
    \frac{x}{n},              & \text{if n is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
so $b_n = \frac{x}{n}(-1)^{n+1}$ for $n=1,2,3,..$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not use the integral limits
$$b_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{0} xsin(nx) dx
\\=\frac{1}{\pi}\left( \frac{-x}{n}cos(nx) \right)|_{-\pi}^0+\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{0} \frac{cos(nx)}{n} dx
\\= \frac{-1}{n}cos(n\pi) + 0
\\=\frac{-1}{n}(-1)^{n+1}$$

Therefore, $b_n = \frac{-1}{n}(-1)^{n+1}$